# VS Code / Apex Debugging - Error Setting Checkpoints: Required fields are missing: [ExecutableEntityId]

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, checkpoint

I am using VS Code to debug apex code. I am getting the following error when I try to update checkpoints (SFDX: Update Checkpoints in Org):

Required fields are missing: [ExecutableEntityId]. URI=file:///Users/mark/projects/aeo-sfdc/force-app/main/default/classes/QualtricsMock.cls, Line=13

Other checkpoints are not giving me errors.  Just when I try to set a checkpoint on this Mock class: QualtricsMock.

Attached image shows the code, checkpoint (line 13) and error message.

Any ideas?

[image: error setting checkpoint]

Comment: Sanity check: Is the code you're trying to set checkpoints on present in the org you're running the debug session on (i.e. the default org in your sfdx project)?

Comment: @DerekF Yes. It is a sandbox with all the code.